How to sign specific parts of a wcf client soap message?
I have to communicate with a soap service that requires me to sign specific parts of the message. I can configure this in soapUI, as in image below. I need to sign the WSA headers from and to, the timestamp and the body.
I cannot seem to find the correct place to configure this. I get most of the way it seems with the code below. But where in the custombinding do I specify the correct parts to sign?

 WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
 binding.Security = new WSHttpSecurity()
 {
     Mode = SecurityMode.Transport,
     Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
     {
         ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate,
     }
 };

 CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);

 UpdateBinding(customBinding);

 private static void UpdateBinding(CustomBinding binding)
 {
    

     var sec = SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement();
     sec.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Sha256;
     sec.IncludeTimestamp = true;

     binding.Elements.Insert(0, sec);
    
 }



You need to set the mode to SecurityMode.Message and set the clientCredentialType of the message element to MessageCredentialType.Certificate. And then set up a endpoint behavior and configure the clientCertificate element to indicate where the client certificate is stored.

@jiayao I would need TransportWithMessageCredential not message as I still need to access it over https. Also this does not answer as to how to only sign specific elements like the wsa headers to and from. By default only to and timestamp seem to get signed.
